# Where can I find all possible processes in a Linux system?

Tags: linux, process

Can I find all possible processes for a Linux system (Ubuntu)? Not just currently running ones but all that would be there if all native processes were up.

Comment: "All possible processes", even the ones we write next week? That's a high order infinity!

Comment: I want to create an application that checks which processes are not reliable. I need a reference for that. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Yes, all numbers from 1 to whatever is in `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` are possible process IDs.

Comment: PIDs can change. I'm asking bout names.

Comment: Worth noting that procs that are not running are not necessarily unreliable. There is just no need to run things like `systemd-remount-fs.service` constantly -- unless of course you want to always-be-remounting

Comment: A process ID cannot change (and ID that can change is not really an ID). Any string is a possible process name, and a process name *can* change during the lifetime of a process. Perhaps you are thinking about some other entities, like executable files, rather than processes.

Comment: The id of a _running_ process will not change, but process ids are reused in Linux

Answer (score 1):

To check all available process that can be 'live' you can find all executables in system:

```
sudo find / -executable -type f
```

Notice that this will also report libraries. This will check along all filesystems mounted at this moment

Comment: Is there a way to strip out libraries from the result?

Comment: You could to invoke `file` and check if is executable or shared object: example `file -b /bin/ls` in my system return `ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64`.

Answer (score 0):

System processes? In Ubuntu 15.04+, all the services that run under systemd can be found with

```
systemctl list-units -t service
```

That says nothing of services users start or services started by other services, though.